# ImportError: cannot import name 'CdworkshopStack' from 'cdworkshop.cdworkshop_stack'

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Getting the following error when trying to run cdk diff:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***/cdworkshop/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cdworkshop.cdworkshop_stack import CdworkshopStack
ImportError: cannot import name 'CdworkshopStack' from 'cdworkshop.cdworkshop_stack'
```

This is my app.py code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from cdworkshop.cdworkshop_stack import CdworkshopStack


app = core.App()
CdworkshopStack(app, "cdworkshop", env={'region': 'us-west-2'})

app.synth()
```

And for fun, here is where the class is defined:

```
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
)


class CdkworkshopStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # Defines an AWS Lambda resource
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
            code=_lambda.Code.asset('lambda'),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )
```

I have no idea what the issue is! Is it a path issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are running - `app.py` - is in a folder called `cdworkshop`. Therefore,

```
from cdworkshop.cdworkshop_stack import CdworkshopStack
```

is looking for a class named `CdworkshopStack` in a file called `cdworkshop_stack.py` *in the same folder*. I'm guessing the import is failing because either that file or the class don't exist there.

To get your program to import from a package installed in `site-packages`, which is probably what you really want, just change the name of the folder `app.py` is in.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback!